# Most user-friendly way to insert data into table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

So I am attempting to learn PHP and SQL and made a mock auction website. I have a webpage where you can browse items, on each item I have a button "bid on this item".

I am trying to figure out a user friendly option for adding bids to that specific item. the solution i have come up with now, is a register bid page, where you pick the item in a drop down menu and select the user you want the bid registered on. I am aware either user or item should be selected by drop-down menu, but for simplicity i will keep the user as a dropdown choice. What i am looking for is to improve how the item value gets added. This is not user-friendly for the obvious reason that it requires the user to input the `itemID`. I am wondering how i can make so that when you browse the item page, and you see an item you want to bid on, you can press bid button in the item column, that automatically enters the `itemID` for the item you pressed bid on. Making it so that you just input your username, and the bid amount.

To summarize: How can I have a register bid link that upon pressing redirects you to a bidding page, where the bid gets registered to the item of which button you pressed. Please forgive my attempt to describe my issue. I am looking for ways to do this in SQL or PHP. Maybe using  `$_GET`?

**SQL Table Structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE `bid` (
   `idbid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `amount` INT NOT NULL,
   `idbuyer` INT NULL,
   `iditem` INT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`idbid`)
);

CREATE TABLE `item` (
   `iditem` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `min_price` INT NULL,
   `description` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
   `idseller` INT NULL,
   `idcategory` INT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`iditem`)
);

CREATE TABLE `seller` (
    `idseller` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idseller`)
);

ALTER TABLE `bid` 
    ADD INDEX `FK_item_idx` (`iditem` ASC);
ALTER TABLE `bid` 
    ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_item`
    FOREIGN KEY (`iditem`)
    REFERENCES `item` (`iditem`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

ALTER TABLE `item` 
    ADD INDEX `FK_seller_idx` (`idseller` ASC);
ALTER TABLE `item` 
    ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_seller`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idseller`)
    REFERENCES `seller` (`idseller`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

INSERT INTO `item` (`min_price`, `description`) VALUES ('200', 'coffeetable');
INSERT INTO `item` (`min_price`, `description`) VALUES ('400', 'lamp');
INSERT INTO `item` (`min_price`, `description`) VALUES ('600', 'painting');

INSERT INTO `bid` (`amount`, `iditem`) VALUES ('800', '1');
INSERT INTO `bid` (`amount`,`iditem`) VALUES ('1000','2');

INSERT INTO `seller` (`name`) VALUES ('Bob');
INSERT INTO `seller` (`name`) VALUES ('Rob');
INSERT INTO `seller` (`name`) VALUES ('Tob');

UPDATE `item` SET `idseller`='1' WHERE `iditem`='1';
UPDATE `item` SET `idseller`='1' WHERE `iditem`='2';
UPDATE `item` SET `idseller`='2' WHERE `iditem`='3';
```

Comment: This looks like a UI question, not a data modelling question. Your data model looks fine. I would say use the userId from login to fill in the idbuyer and idseller

Answer (score 1):

Authenticate the bidders before bidding to avoid the frustration of logging on while placing a bid.

Assuming you have multiple auction items listed together, use a JavaScript click event to select the itemID that the bidder has selected.  Use AJAX to get the most recent bid amount to allow only increasing bids.

For fast bidding and updating, send the bids via AJAX and periodically refresh via AJAX.

Review eBay auctions -- they are the masters.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, as I am a complete beginner to php sql i do not have a log in system for my users table, you just select you name in a drop down menu, I will update my question to clearify that better.  As for JavaScript and AJAX, as I am sure that your suggestion is the best solution to my question, however I have never used either and I am not yet comfortable enough to attempt it, i was wondering if there is any way to do this with MySQLi or PHP?

Comment: Of course you will use MySQL and PHP.  Without AJAX you will be recreating and reloading the entire page for any action that requires communication with the server.

Answer (score 0):

Using $_GET you can get the ID from the item on your item page. Link your register bid page as `href="givebid.php?bidID=<?php echo $row ['IDitem'];?>`in the button for "give bid".